# How to get a 1 click PayPal check out button on cs-cart?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, cs-cart

For my e-commerce store using the cs-cart platform, I want a PayPal checkout with 1 click

Answer (score 0):

Any PayPal Checkout or (older name) "Express Checkout" payment method will allow PayPal's "One Touch" login, if the customer has opted in on that device before.

If you are looking for something that allows 1 click on your site to charge the customer, that would require Reference Transactions being enabled for the receiving PayPal business account (which PayPal does NOT give approval for easily), a module that supports this, and a previous checkout by the customer on your website to agree to the billing agreement.